# How to find an integer's position in the fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, sorting, math, ranking, fibonacci

I'm trying to use fibonacci's sequence as limits for a game's experience points to level conversion (i would like critics on that decision too), something like this:

If a player has 49.450 points, he's in level 25, because the closest smaller fibonacci number is 46.368.

I'm having trouble, however, to figure out how to do that. Apart from creating a map with levels as keys and limits as values, is there any smarter way?

Comment: if the number of level is limited , then I think creating  an initial map is the best option.

Comment: yes, also that would help with tailoring the values later, i'm willing to do that too. any comment about the fibonnaci idea? is there a better idea to create level limits that increase in size?

Comment: Using Fibonacci for this is quite cool. You need to consider how steeply you want the difficulty of moving to the next level to grow as the game progress. Maybe draw a curve on a piece of paper and then see which basic mathematical function can give you that curve.

Comment: For large n, the nth fibonnaci number is about c*phi^n, where phi is the golden ratio.  You could tweak the constants to get a level progression to your liking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fibonacci grows exponentially. The base is phi (the golden ratio), so it's not quite as fast as 2^n, but it's still pretty fast. only the smallest 94 or so Fibonacci numbers can be represented by an unsigned 64-bit integer, so a lookup table is probably your best option.

However, if you really did want to compute it, you could invert the closed form solution to get something like:

```
int fibIndex(long n) {
    return Math.round(Math.log(n * Math.sqrt(5))/Math.log(PHI));
}
```

this may be of by one, and of course cannot distinguish between the double 1s early in the sequence.